# Shifting an integer to get an ARGB gray

Tags: java, colors

Let's say i have:

```
int x = 140;
```

And i want to get the result of:

```
int y = new Color(x, x, x).getRGB()
```

From Java API documentation:

> getRGB()
>   
> Gets the RGB value representing the color in the default RGB ColorModel.
>   
> (bits 24-31 are 0xff, 16-23 are red, 8-15 are green, 0-7 are blue)

But i'm not sure about how shifting works, is this right?

```
 int y = 0xff + x<<16 + x<<8 + x;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your approach would work if you don't forgot to shift correctly the alpha value.

```
int y = (0xff<<24) + (x<<16) + (x<<8) + x;
```

However a common approach is to directly shift the bits (with a combination of left shift and bitwise or). I presume because it's faster to apply the bitwise than the addition and it's enough readable to manipulate ARGB values for a human.

```
int y = (0xff<<24) | (x<<16) | (x<<8) | x;
```

You can view it like this.

```
(0xff << 24) =>  0xff000000
| (x<<16)    =>  0xff8c0000
| (x<<8)     =>  0xff8c8c00
| x          =>  0xff8c8c8c
```

Comment: Thanks! Could you explain me why i need the bitwise or please? :)

Comment: adding 0xff000000 with 0x008c0000 without the bitwise or doesn't give me 0xff8c0000 ?

Comment: @XandruDavid My apologies you were right, but you need to shift correctly the alpha value.